# What did the Red Lights signify?

Tags: plot-explanation, red-lights

In the movie *Red Lights*, what exactly did the red lights mean, both within the movie title and the plot?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this review on The Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/marshall-fine/movie-review-ired-lightsi_b_1682479.html):

> the title refers to **warning signs of fraud that trained debunkers
>   should be able to spot**

[This review on AXS](https://www.axs.com/red-lights-takes-its-title-almost-too-literal-with-pacing-91854) explains this a bit more:

> Red Lights follows two paranormal investigators who set out to debunk
>   fraudulent mind readers, ghost hunters, faith healers and the like by
>   detecting what they call **'red lights', subtle clues to the trickery
>   behind each of these 'supernatural' occurrences**.

And [here's Den Of Geek](http://www.denofgeek.com/movies/red-lights/21658/red-lights-review):

> Red Lights' title, we learn, is **a reference to the practice of
>   spotting a spiritualist huckster's tell-tale tricks**.

It is also explained somewhat in this piece of dialogue:

> - You know, there are two kinds of people out there with a special gift: The ones who really think they have some kind of power and the other guys... who think we can't figure them out. They're both wrong.
>
> [...]
>
> - So what are we looking for?
> - Red lights.
> - Red lights
> - Discordant notes, things that shouldn't be there.